# Check update from own app (no market)

Tags: android

Slowly...very slowly...I building my first app.. now I'd like an automatic check of update of it from my web server.

So, I need add the code to my app to check if there any update when I start my app.

I done a long search on internet but I didn't find any example code...

Someone can get that code?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you would want to put some sort of a server request. You should return what the latest version is of your code, and check that from your code against it's version. I suggest outputting a JSON array, which there are a multitude of libraries to do so.

You will want to do a CGI of some kind, some language like PHP, Python, Ruby or Perl most likely. And then you will have to find a place to host it. Of those languages, I would suggest Python, for no real reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current version of your app (that you set in your AndroidManifest.xml) like so:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionCode
```

Now you have to put your latest app version number on a server, retrieve it and compare it to the above version. If the server gives you a higher version number than the local one, you have to perfom an update (for example by displaying a notification).

Answer (score 0):

String currentVersion, version, downloadPath;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.devicecontrol);
        PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        currentVersion = pInfo.versionCode // Give your current version 


        if(isOnline())
         new getSettingsTask().execute();       

}


// Put an settings xml to the server which old app info    

private class getSettingsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

        @Override

        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                final Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();

                uri.scheme("http");
                uri.authority("DOMAIN or IP");
                uri.path("virtualpath/settings.xml");

                URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("settings");

                Log.v("data :", "length : " + nodeList.getLength());

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;


                    NodeList versionList = fstElmnt
                            .getElementsByTagName("androidversion");
                    Element versionElement = (Element) versionList.item(0);
                    versionList = versionElement.getChildNodes();

                    NodeList dpList = fstElmnt
                            .getElementsByTagName("androiddownloadpath");
                    Element dpElement = (Element) dpList.item(0);
                    dpList = dpElement.getChildNodes();

                    version = (versionList.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString();
                    downloadPath = (dpList.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            try {
                if (currentVersion.equals(version)) {
                    // IT IS OK GO 
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            devicecontrol.this);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                    builder.setTitle("Please download new version...");
                    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    try {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        i.setData(Uri.parse(downloadPath));
                                        startActivity(i);
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        System.exit(getTaskId());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        message(e.toString());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    System.exit(getTaskId());
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            ;
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

**Your xml on the server look like below,**

Your App Version
             Download Path

Answer (score 0):

just put a textfile with the actual versionNumber on your webserver. on startup you get the value via a HttpRequest. Then you can do something like this:

```
int localVersionNumber = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
int serverVersionnumber = GetVersionNumberFromInternet();

if(serverVersionnumber > localVersionNumber)
{
 //new version is available...  ask the user if the wants to update
 // if true --->
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
+ getPackageName());
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(marketUri);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few `open-source` (licensed under the Apache Software License 2.0) options you may check and see how it works.

1. http://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/ is the android client for the auto update service (i'm affiliated with), which is small, easy to implement and supports silent updates on rooted devices.
2. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater is written by Mark Murphy, however it might require you to run your own update server and I'm not sure about silent updates.